# C# - Cannot convert convert lambda expression to listitem

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
Title="xxxxxxx yyyyyyy zzzzzz 1234RED 987";

Value="1234RED";


if (!dialogItems.Exists(x => x.Title == value))

    throw new InvalidOperationException($"List does not have {value}.");
```

above code is working fine which will compare with title.

I need to compare the values by **Contains** instead of **Title** 
 need direction

other words - Partial string matches are allowed

Comment: what is `dialogItems`, what you are trying to achieve? Please provide code

Comment: `if (!dialogItems.Exists(x => x.Title.Contains(value)))`?

Comment: @Sweeper - Thank you it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below variants of lambda expression to validate `Contains`

**A)** You can check if `Title` contains `value` with

1) `Exist`

```
if (!dialogItems.Exists(x => x.Title.Contains(value)))
```

OR

2) `Any`

```
if (!dialogItems.Any(x => x.Title.Contains(value)))
```

**B)** You can check if `Title` contains `value` with trimming all leading and trailing white spaces and lowering the case of both title and value. It causes more chances to match your value with Title

1) `Exist`

```
if (!dialogItems.Exists(x => x.Title.Trim().ToLower().Contains(value.Trim().ToLower())))
```

OR

2) `Any`

```
if (!dialogItems.Any(x => x.Title.Trim().ToLower().Contains(value.Trim().ToLower())))
```

Comment: it worked, thank you very much for providing detailed info